# Javascript drawImage function fail

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

I've played around with the draw function but now that i'm moving on to images i've hit a brick wall. here is the code:

```
var x
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ghost = new Image();
ghost.src = "ghost.png"

window.setTimeout(x, 5000);


var drawIm = function (sprite) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(100, 100);
    ctx.drawImage(sprite, 0, 0, sprite.width, sprite.height, 0, 0, sprite.width, sprite.height);
    ctx.restore();
};


drawIm(ghost);
```

I'm sure it's nothing to do with the file names or anything, and i can't see any problem with it, but the ghost just won't appear! What's the problem?

Comment: maybe the ghost img is not loaded when you are drawing in the canvas. Try to draw the image on onload event of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw the ghost when it's loaded. SO, do something like ...

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ghost = new Image();

//ghost onload event
ghost.onload = function() {
   drawIm(ghost);
}

ghost.src = "https://lessonpix.com/drawings/2587/100x100/Happy+Ghost.png";

var drawIm = function(sprite) {
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(100, 100);
   ctx.drawImage(sprite, 0, 0, sprite.width, sprite.height, 0, 0, sprite.width, sprite.height);
   ctx.restore();
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: He did use a 5 second timeout before drawing, though. Although it's good to mention how to load an image properly, it may not work still.

Comment: yes it will. as you can clearly see on the snippet `(:`

Comment: Thanks! it worked, but why didn't the 5 second timeout?

Comment: bcoz, you are not using `setTimeout` in a correct way. though you shouldn't use it in this case at all.

Comment: k. Thanks again!

Comment: You should load ALL your image assets prior to doing anything, to be honest. And update an array of booleans or something and only proceed when all the booleans are true, i.e. all images have loaded.